# 2 Lists - Check checkbox for elements that match - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, loops, logic

I have 2 lists of different types -

List
List

The db tables are structured as follows

```
Product
-----------
ProductID - PK
Name
Description
Price
OwnerID - FK
...

SelectedProducts
---------------
SelectedProductID - PK
ProductID - FK
Active
```

So I have a page where the user is displayed a list of products, they can select some or all of the products. I am now trying to create an edit page which displays a full list of products, but checks the checkboxes for products already selected.

I have tried the following approaches, however both give me duplicates of some sort -

**Approach 1**
This approach gives me a list of products, and then duplicates the products because of the ones already selected.

```
    <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <% foreach (var product in Model.Products) { %>
        <% foreach (var p in Model.SelectedProducts)
           { %>
           <% if (p.ProductID == product.ProductID)
              { %>
                <div style="float: left; line-height: 18px; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: middle;
                        border: 1px solid grey; width: 282px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRODUCT_<%: product.Name %>" value="<%: ViewData["PRODUCT_" + product.ProductID] %>" checked="checked" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 5px;" />
                        <%: Html.Truncate(product.Name, 35) %>
                </div>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
            <div style="float: left; line-height: 18px; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: middle;
                    border: 1px solid grey; width: 282px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="PRODUCT_<%: product.Name %>" value="<%: ViewData["PRODUCT_" + product.ProductID] %>" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 5px;" />
                    <%: Html.Truncate(product.Name, 35) %>
            </div>
        <% } %>        
    </div>
```

**Approach 2**

```
<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
        <% foreach (var product in Model.Products) { %>
            <% foreach (var p in Model.SelectedProducts)
               { %>
               <% if (p.ProductID == product.ProductID)
                  { %>
        <div style="float: left; line-height: 18px; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: middle;
                        border: 1px solid grey; width: 282px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRODUCT_<%: product.Name %>" value="<%: ViewData["PRODUCT_" + product.ProductID] %>" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 5px;" />
                        <%: Html.Truncate(product.Name, 35) %>
          </div>
        <% } else { %>
         <div style="float: left; line-height: 18px; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid grey; width: 282px;">
         <input type="checkbox" name="PRODUCT_<%: product.Name %>" value="<%: ViewData["PRODUCT_" + product.ProductID] %>" checked="checked" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 5px;" />
                      <%: Html.Truncate(product.Name, 35) %>
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>        
    </div>
```

I know it's just a silly logic error but I could do with a fresh pair of eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the inner loop and instead just test each item in the outerloop against your selected products list, you should be good to go:

```
<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
        <% foreach (var product in Model.Products) { %>
        <% if (Model.SelectedProducts.Exists(x => x.ProductId == product.ProductId))
                  { %>
        <div style="float: left; line-height: 18px; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: middle;
                        border: 1px solid grey; width: 282px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRODUCT_<%: product.Name %>" value="<%: ViewData["PRODUCT_" + product.ProductID] %>" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 5px;" />
                        <%: Html.Truncate(product.Name, 35) %>
          </div>
        <% } else { %>
         <div style="float: left; line-height: 18px; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid grey; width: 282px;">
         <input type="checkbox" name="PRODUCT_<%: product.Name %>" value="<%: ViewData["PRODUCT_" + product.ProductID] %>" checked="checked" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 5px;" />
                      <%: Html.Truncate(product.Name, 35) %>
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   foreach (var product in Model.Products) {
       if (Model.SelectedProducts.Any(i => i.ProductID == product.Id))
      {
       //Your code
      }
      else
      {
       //Your code
      }
    }
```